# отправка jsona после 2 нажатия на кнопку

Tags: javascript, ajax

Подскажите почему отправка jsona происходит после второго нажатия на кнопку.
Код функции:

```
    function saveChanges() {
    var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
    var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    $("#changeForm").ready(function () {

        $("#changeForm").find("input").each(function () {
            massChanges.push(this.value);
        })
        massChanges.push($( "#cities option:selected" ).text());
        console.log(massChanges);
    })
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/admin/saveChanges",
        // headers : {
        //     'Accept' : 'application/json',
        //     'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        // },
        data: JSON.stringify(massChanges), // Note it is important
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            // here it is
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        },
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", result);
            alert("success" + result);
        }
//                                ,
//                                error: function (result) {
//                                    console.log("ERROR: ", result);
//                                    alert("Error" + result);
//                                }
    });
    massChanges = [];
}
```

Код контроллера:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/admin/saveChanges", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public
@ResponseBody
String saveChanges(@RequestBody List<String> list) {

    System.out.println("SAVECHANGES");
    for (String s:list) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    System.out.println("Success changes");
    return "Success changes";
}
```

После первого нажатия [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоли пусто:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Забыл ещё упомянуть кнопка с помощью скрипта генерируется, то есть подгружается динамически. Аналогичным способом работает кнопка delete, но она почему срабатывает с первого раза, ещё она статична. В общем буду рад любой помощи, дебаг не помогает(

Как цепляется changeForm:

```
function editUser() {
// массив для взятий информации о пользователе из таблицы
    var userInfo = [];

    // $("table").find("tr").each(function () {
    //
    //     if($(this).is(":visible")){
    //         alert("success");
    //         console.log("SUCCESS")
    //     }
    // })
    var count = 0;
    // здесь надо передать одно значение, то есть один ряд с инфой о пользователе иначе кинуть alert
    $("table").find("tr").each(function () {
        if ($(this).find("input").is(":checked")) {
            count++;
        }
    });
    if (count <= 1) {
        $("table").find("tr").each(function () {
            if ($(this).find("input").is(":checked")) {
                $(this).find("td").each(function () {
                    userInfo.push(this.innerHTML);
                })
                return false;
            }
            count = 0;
        });
    }
    else {
        alert("Выбрано больше одного значения");
        if ($("#tableForUser").length != 0) {
            getUsers();
            count = 0;
            return;
        }
        if ($("#tableForOwners").length != 0) {
            getOwners();
            count = 0;
            return;
        }
        if ($("#tableForDrivers").length != 0) {
            getDrivers();
            count = 0;
            return;
        }
    }
    console.log(userInfo);
    // alert("SUCCESS");
    getCities();
    console.log(listCities);

    $("#head").children().remove();
    var trHTML = '';
    trHTML += '<form id="changeForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form">' +
        '<input id="inputID" class="form-control" type="text" style="visibility:hidden">' +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Ник:</label>' +
        '<div class="col-lg-8">' +
        '<input id="inputNick" class="form-control" type="text">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Имя:</label>' +
        '<div class="col-lg-8">' +
        '<input id="inputFirstname" class="form-control" type="text">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Фамилия:</label>' +
        '<div class="col-lg-8">' +
        '<input id="inputLastname" class="form-control" type="text" >' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Мобильный телефон:</label>' +
        '<div class="col-lg-8">' +
        '<input id="inputMobile"class="form-control" type="text">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Электронная почта:</label>' +
        '<div class="col-lg-8">' +
        '<input id="inputEmail" class="form-control" type="text">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Город:</label>' +
        '<div class="col-lg-8">' +
        '<div class="ui-select">' +
        '<select id="cities" class="form-control">' +
        // '<option value="Hawaii">(GMT-10:00) Hawaii</option>' +
        // '<option value="Alaska">(GMT-09:00) Alaska</option>' +
        // '<option value="Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)">(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>' +
        // '<option value="Arizona">(GMT-07:00) Arizona</option>' +
        // '<option value="Mountain Time (US &amp; Canada)">(GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>' +
        // '<option value="Central Time (US &amp; Canada)" selected="selected">(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>' +
        // '<option value="Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada)">(GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US &amp; Canada)</option>' +
        // '<option value="Indiana (East)">(GMT-05:00) Indiana (East)</option>' +
        '</select>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<label class="col-md-3 control-label">Пароль:</label>' +
        '<div class="col-md-8">' +
        '<input id="inputPassword1" class="form-control" type="password">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<label class="col-md-3 control-label">Подтвердите пароль:</label>' +
        '<div class="col-md-8">' +
        '<input id="inputPassword2" class="form-control" type="password">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="form-group">' +
        '<label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>' +
        '<div class="col-md-8">' +
        // '<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveChanges();" value="Save Changes">'
        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveChanges();">Сохранить</button><br>' +
        '<span></span>' +
        '<input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</form>';
    $("#head").append(trHTML);
    if (userInfo[1] == null) {
        alert("Выберите пользователя для редактирования");
        $("#head").children().remove();
    }
    else {
        //Записываем индекс
        // massChanges.push(userInfo[0]);
        // console.log(massChanges);
        document.getElementById("inputID").value = userInfo[0];
        document.getElementById("inputNick").value = userInfo[1];
        document.getElementById("inputFirstname").value = userInfo[2];
        document.getElementById("inputLastname").value = userInfo[3];
        document.getElementById("inputMobile").value = userInfo[4];
        document.getElementById("inputEmail").value = userInfo[5];
        document.getElementById("cities").value = userInfo[6];
        document.getElementById("inputPassword1").value = userInfo[7];
        document.getElementById("inputPassword2").value = userInfo[7];

        userInfo = [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow не позволил ещё две фотки прикрепить(.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `$("#changeForm").ready`. Каким образом `saveChanges`  навешивается?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял:'<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="saveChanges();">Сохранить</button><br>'

Comment: @br3t, добавил, как changeForm цепляется. Извините что сразу не сообразил

Comment: @br3t вы оказались правы, пожалуйста оформите ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет необходимости использовать событие `onready` для "незагружаемых" (т.е. не для элементов с внешними связями (типа `img`, `script` и т.д.) или объекта `document`) элементов, в данном случае - для вставляемой на страницу через `html()` формы.
Т.е. необходимо убрать `$("#changeForm").ready`.